# Power Regulation

Tags: battery-operated, ldo

I have a Li-Ion 3S1P Battery Pack with built in BMS rated:
Typ. Capacity: 5000 mAh
Nominal Voltage: 10.8V – 11.1V
Charging Voltage: 12.6V
Discharging Voltage: 9V

I need to power an [STA540](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sta540.pdf) in stereo plus bridge drive configuration (page 11/25) and I would like to regulate the power supply. If I use an LDO I need to count for at least 1 volt for dropout calculated for my worst case scenario more or less 9v, that is the voltage at which the BMS should disconnect the load, giving me a regulated 8V.

Is my assumption so far correct?

If so I would like to know if there is perhaps a way to higher my regulated voltage  to aim at a higher output power without of course having to change the battery pack.

Comment: Why do you want to regulate the voltage in the first place? You don't have to. The STA540 can take the unregulated battery voltage.

Comment: If the chip accepts a wide voltage range, why regulate it at all? Also the battery discharge  should be stopped at 9V, but it does not mean the BMS will cut it at 9V. The BMS is for protecting the cells from damage by disconnecting them. It might disconnect them at some lower voltage than 9V, and the disconnect may be permanent, and the battery will be useless. It is your circuit that should safely turn off at 9V. Also that is a linear amplifier, if you want longer battery life, why not use a more efficient amplifier?

Comment: It says in the BMS description of the product: “ IC Protection / PCB with protection against short circuit, overcharge and deep discharge”. I thought that it cuts off discharge current when the cell voltage reaches the overdischarge threshold.

Comment: The datasheet shows an output of less than only 3W per channel when bridged with a 4 ohms speaker and an 8V supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your supply voltage is already quite low for the STA540. The chip can directly consume your battery voltage without any regulation, so *don't* add a regulator. You don't need it and it will just limit the maximum output power for no good reason.

Additionally, please add a proper under-voltage lock-out to the amplifier that turns it off at your target discharge voltage of 9V. The BMS over-discharge protection is only a last line of defense, and when it triggers, the battery may have already been damaged.